# cdetailview and cgridview customise css style in yii

Tags: css, yii, cgridview, cdetailview

I am using both cwidgets i.e., cdetailview and cgridview I have displayed it using renderPartial method .

The thing thing is That I need to change my css to it for beautification.I am well versed with css styling but to these widgets, how do I apply it in yii? thats the big question to me, I did walk through all forum pages yet my need is not satisfied.

following is the code

**viewb**

```
 <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
 'data' => array(),
  //to avoid error
 'attributes' => $res,
 'cssFile'=>Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/css/mecss.css',));
?>
```

cssFile doesn't work have copy pasted the assets detailview code and applied my css yet no change

**controllerb**

```
$this->renderPartial('viewB',array('res'=>$res));
```

**viewc**

```
  <?php
   $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
   'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
  'ajaxUpdate'=>true,
 'columns'=>array(
 array('name'=>' Name','value'=>'$data["name"]'),
 array('name'=>' status','value'=>'$data["status"]'),
 ),
 ));
 ?>
```

**controllerc**

```
$this->renderPartial('viewc',array(
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        ));
```

this is the view what am looking for

[image: Cdetailview using ajax with customise css]

all the attributes are from the same table's record which i have provided as $res to detailview but then i need deatils, credential details and expirarydetails  as headers for respective attributes .is it possible? if yes please guide else what else can i do so to achieve it please let me know.

am displaying it in modelA and modelD view respectively using ajax

to each i wanna apply my css style but then i dont know how do i start

i do know their's an attribute cssFile am tryng with it can anyone guide for it or any good way.

Please guide let me know how do i achieve it

Comment: what type of css do you want to apply? i mean do you want to change the style of the header? Do you want to change the style of the cell? Do you want to change the the color of text in cells?

Comment: sorry for the delay for respones hv update my question with the view i need n dts d stylei wanna apply please let me know can it b done?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can apply your custom Css. Some attributes are used for this like

```
cssFile
filterCssClass
itemsCssClass
loadingCssClass
pagerCssClass
rowCssClass
rowCssClassExpression
summaryCssClass
```

And yes here is the demo with custom Css properties.
http://www.yiiplayground.com/index.php?r=UiModule/dataview/gridStyle

Answer (score 0):

you can set all sorts of classes for your CGridView :

[class for your row](http://yiiapi.com/CGridView#rowCssClass-detail)

[class for filter row](http://yiiapi.com/CGridView#filterCssClass-detail)

[rowCssClassExpression](http://yiiapi.com/CGridView#rowCssClassExpression-detail)

> a PHP expression that is evaluated for every table body row and whose
>   result is used as the CSS class name for the row.

Comment: sorry for the delay for respones hv update my question with the view i need n dts d stylei wanna apply please let me know can it b done?

Comment: is their any demo for your abv provided link i did read but then i dont know how do i implement  it

Answer (score 0):

The following code will apply CSS class from Bootstrap 3 framework to detail view:

```
<?php 
 $this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
 'data' => array(),
 'htmlOptions' => array('class' => 'table table-striped table-bordered table-hovered table-condensed'),
  //to avoid error
 'attributes' => $res,
 'cssFile'=>Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/css/mecss.css',));
?>
```

Basically, you can use the `htmlOptions` property to apply whatever style or HTML attribute you want (everthing, [based on tag name](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDetailView#htmlOptions-detail)).